JsonConverter. VS.net does not allow implementation of abstract class / NewtonsoftJson
i'm trying to implement a JsonConverter, with this code:

public class TimestampStringConverter : JsonConverter<TimestampString>
{
    public sealed override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        bool existingIsNull = existingValue == null;
        if (!(existingIsNull || existingValue is T))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Converter cannot read JSON with the specified existing value. {0} is required.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeof(T)));
        }
        return ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingIsNull ? default : (T?)existingValue, !existingIsNull, serializer);
    }
}

it says always: CS0115 - no suitable method found to override - and its marking the line "ReadJson(..)"
and this is the Code in the NewtonsoftJson file:

    public abstract class JsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        public sealed override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (!(value != null ? value is T : ReflectionUtils.IsNullable(typeof(T))))
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Converter cannot write specified value to JSON. {0} is required.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeof(T)));
            }
            WriteJson(writer, (T?)value, serializer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        public abstract void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializer serializer);

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
        /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
        /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
        public sealed override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            bool existingIsNull = existingValue == null;
            if (!(existingIsNull || existingValue is T))
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Converter cannot read JSON with the specified existing value. {0} is required.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, typeof(T)));
            }
            return ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingIsNull ? default : (T?)existingValue, !existingIsNull, serializer);
        }

---- rest of the file


so:
what im doing wrong?
The method is in the base class, i copied even the original signature into the new class - nontheless VS.NET keeps saying "CS0115"
Is this a bug in the IDE?
Regardless with which function from the baseclass: VS.NET always claims there is no method that i can overwrite, while i see them clearly in the file from NewtonsoftJson?
Any ideas?

i was expecting that i could implement the abstract class and override all of its functions
i searched already Google to check if someone else had this problem, since this looks like a bug in VS.NET


As an aside, the answer to "Is this a bug in the IDE?" is almost always no. It's best to assume that the problem is somewhere in your code - 99% of the time, that will help you get to an answer faster than "This doesn't make sense to me, so I suspect it's a bug in the compiler/IDE/whatever."

Note: the code you've provided doesn't give the error you've specified, although it does give 6 other errors. Please provide a [mcve].

Don't you want to have public class TimestampStringConverter<T> : JsonConverter? Or have TimestampString instead of T and cast to / test this Type instead of T?

Look at this in the Json.NET code:
public sealed override object? ReadJson

See the sealed modifier? That means you can't override it.
Although I'd expect to see a different error, CS0239: "cannot override inherited member ... because it is sealed". That's actually the error I get with the code you've provided - along with additional errors because you're using T without declaring it anywhere.
Standalone example:
public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public abstract void M1();
    public abstract void M2();
    public abstract void M3();
}

public abstract class AbstractDerived : AbstractBase
{
    // This can still be overridden in derived classes
    public override void M1() {}

    // This can't be overridden
    public sealed override void M2() {}

    // M3 is still abstract, so *must* be overridden
}

public abstract class Concrete : AbstractDerived
{
    public override void M1() {}
    // Uncomment the line below to see an error
    // public override void M2() {}
    public override void M3() {}
}

The method you should actually be overriding is this:
public abstract T? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
    T? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)

The easiest way to know what you should override is to ask VS to implement the abstract class for you (with stubs that just throw exceptions). Create an empty class:
public class TimestampStringConverter : JsonConverter<TimestampString>
{
}

... then put the cursor in TimestampStringConverter, press Ctrl-., then select "Implement abstract class". You'll end up with this code:
public class TimestampStringConverter : JsonConverter<TimestampString>
{
    public override TimestampString? ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        TimestampString? existingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, TimestampString? value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


Errr, yes, but then this whole JsonConverter-implementor-class makes no sense? What is your suggested solution? Since this is the original JsonConverter file from newtonsoft - what do they expect then? The thing is, if i remove the override tag, then VS.NET says: "does not implement abstract function XYZ" - thats the thing: i do not know what to do, and how to solve this?

@VSDeveloper: No, because the "rest of file" includes an abstract method that you do override: public abstract T? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)

THANKS a lot - you saved me a lot of headache throughout the weekend! I mixed it up with what functoin i actually have to override/not override. ITS WORKING NOW !!!!! thanks :)))))
